# Autowiring in spring (property name and bean name must be same)

Tags: java, spring, autowired

```
public class B {

    public B(){
        System.out.println("B is created");
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("hello b");
    }

}
```

class B.java

```
public class A {

    B c;
    public A(){

        System.out.println("a is created");
    }

    public B getB(){
        return c;
    }

    public void setB(B c){
    this.c =c;
    }

    void print(){
        System.out.println("hello a");
    }

    void display(){
        print();

        c.print();
    }
}
```

class A.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> 
<bean id="b" class="B"></bean>

<bean id="a" class="A" autowire="byName"></bean>

</beans>
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");

        A a1 = context.getBean("a",A.class);
        a1.display();

    }
}
```

Test .java

i was going through the tutorials on autowiring in spring by using "byName" mode. and it says- **The byName mode injects the object dependency according to name of the bean. In such case, property name and bean name must be same. It internally calls setter method.**

but in this application the property name and the bean name both are different but it still works fine,so how this autowiring is working even though the both names are different?

Comment: what is the question? .. anyway works fine because you have into A class the method setB that implicit way to property named b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says **property name**, not **field name**.

Property name in this case is inferred from the setter method name as defined by the JavaBeans naming convention (`setB` -> `b`), thus property name and bean name are the same.

Comment: wait axtavt ,so it means the naming convention should only match not the exact words of property  name and bean name?

Comment: [JavaBeans naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) link property name with the setter name of that property. So, in your case property name is derived from the setter name.